# Need an explanation of this paragraph "Lebesgue Homoeomorphism"

Tags: measure-theory

I will just quote a part of one proof in "On uniformly regular topological measure spaces by Babiker: page 781" vol43 No4 Duke Math. J. 1976.

> Let $I$ be the unit interval endowed with Lebesgue measure $m$. If $\mu$ is nonatomic probability (Radon) measure on (compact) space $X$, then there is $E\subset X$, $D\subset I$ with $\mu(E)=m(D)=0$ and a map $\psi\colon X\rightarrow I$ such that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism from $X\setminus E$ onto $I\setminus D$ and $m=\psi(\mu)$.

The author refer to this reference: N. Bourbaki, Elements De Mathematique Integration I, chaps 1-5, Paris, 1965: in chapter V page 85.

I do not know French to look at it. Could someone give me some steps proving the above result.

**I have posted in MS, but no one interested in answering it, and it is research so I duplicated here**

Comment: There is an English translation by Berberian.

Comment: In fact it is an exercise in Bourbaki and he requires $X$ to be second-countable/metrisable.

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space? 

Comment: It is ok, I need the prove even when $X$ is metric space.

Comment: Here is link to the post on [math.se]: [Need an explanation of this paragraph “Measure Theory”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397199).